# Launch a process with java and then terminate it

Tags: java, processbuilder

Normally I use this code to run a bash script and get it's output

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/myscript");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String inputRead;
p.waitFor();
while((inputRead=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
    Helper.log(inputRead);
}
```

This works fine but this time the bash script I am using didn't terminate. It's always active and when it detect something it print it. I want to start the script, wait for some time and than check if it detected something.

I tried this code

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
p.destroy();
String inputRead;
while((inputRead=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
    Helper.log(inputRead);
}
```

But I get as result

> java.io.IOException: Stream closed

I also tried

```
p.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        while((inputRead=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
            Helper.log(inputRead);
        }
```

But the process never ended and I still get the input in the log for ever.

I just want to run the script for a short period of time, in this example 5 seconds and than stop it and get the output generated by the script in this period.

Answer (score 0):

[Process.destroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) *might* (and probably will, but this is implementation dependent) kill your process and this is why you're getting your **java.io.IOException**.

If you're using Java 8, I'd suggest using [Process.waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) with the timeout constructor. You'll be able to check whether your process has hanged or not. If it returns **true**, you will have captured the process output using normal means. If it returns **false**, your process *might* have hanged, so you can either terminate it, or wait some more and try to see if anything has changed.

An alternative would be to control your bash script using the [timeout](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command, so you can be sure that your script will eventually terminate in a finite amount of time.